# mysqli_query returns unexpected output

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a beginner programmer and am having a little trouble getting information from database through `mysqli_query`. I first connect to the database and then attempt to get the information from the table cbo which is inside the database. I then print out what results from the query which is not the information from the table. Instead this is what I get.

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 8
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 12
    [type] => 0
)
```

Here is the code I am using. Dump just echos the variable.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "harvard", "cbo projections");
    if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cbo");
    dump( $result );
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is just an object that contains the resultset. You have to fetch data from it. Read [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) or [mysqli_fetch_array](https://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //Display fields here according to your table structure
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

You could do something like

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $records[]=$row;
    }
```

This will create an array named records that will contain all your fetched rows and then you can later access that array and process accordingly

Comment: thank you. im getting the first row now. how would i loop to get the others?

Comment: is there any way I could store each row from my table into a separate variable list?

Answer (score 2):

That's the mysqli object, what do you want to do with it? You should read about https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php, https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php or https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php.

By example:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "harvard", "cbo projections");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cbo");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cbo");
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: thanks. the only problem is that I only get the first row. how would i get the rest of the rows?

Comment: Odil This will not work as expected. You have mistakenly mixed mysqli with mysql extension